# Youtube Searching API

Tags: php, api, youtube

I would like to search Videos using YouTube php data API, but my aim is to show only authorized embedded videos. I tried to use `setFormat` method, but it doesn't work for me!

Here is my code :

```
 <?php  

        $searchQuery = $yt->newVideoQuery();
        $searchQuery->setVideoQuery($query);
        $searchQuery->setCategory('Music');
        $searchQuery->setMaxResults(10);
        $searchQuery->setFormat(5); //ICI
        echo $searchQuery->getQueryUrl(2);
        $videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed($searchQuery->getQueryUrl(2));
    ....
    ?>
```

But I still get non-embedded authorized videos.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following link: [Use the YouTube API with PHP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-youtubeapi/). They have a nicely done search YouTube video using data API.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a GET parameter (from your post I can't tell if you are using a POST or a GET).

The [Youtube API Reference Guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference) shows Querying for videos with a GET parameters "&format=5"

Look at the section titled: Searching for videos

Good luck!